# GCM for Google TV

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-tv

We are developing smart TV(Google) based application. In that application we just want to implement GCM concept to reduce the network traffic between server and client.

My question is will this GCM support for Google TV also?(Just like Android phones) or are there any restrictions?
We are targeting for the for smart TV OS version 5.0 and above.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is "smart TV(Google)"? What is "smart TV OS version 5.0"? What does [the discontinued Google TV product line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_TV) have to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## All i can say that

Google Cloud Messaging is a service that allows you to establish a communication channel with a device (typically, Android-based). It has nothing to do on the way you display the received data! Since Google/Android TV is Android-based, GCM will work just fine on it.

## The Only thing which can differ is

Way to show/display notifications.